# Add jQuery variable to string

Tags: jquery

I have got this far with my code, which is to duplicate a Billing Address to a Shipping Address on a form:

**JQUERY**

```
$("#toshipping_checkbox").on("click",function(){
  var formid = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
  var idsplit = formid.split('_');

  console.log(idsplit[0]);

    var ship = $(this).is(":checked");
    $("[id^='form1_shipping_']").each(function(){
      var tmpID = this.id.split('form1_shipping_')[1];
      $(this).val(ship?$("#form1_"+tmpID).val():"");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Billing Address</h2>
 <div>
     <label class="required" for="form1_address_1">Address 1</label>
     <input id="form1_address_1" name="address_1" type="text" required="required" />

 </div>

 <div>
     <label for="form1_address_2">Address 2</label>
     <input id="form1_address_2" name="address_2" type="text" />
 </div>

 <div>
     <label for="form1_city">City</label>
     <input id="form1_city" name="city" type="text" />
 </div>

<h2>Shipping Address</h2>
<label for="toshipping_checkbox">Tick this box if Shipping Address and Billing Address are the same.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toshipping_checkbox">
<div>
     <label class="required" for="form1_shipping_address_1">Address 1</label>
     <input id="form1_shipping_address_1" name="shipping_address_1" type="text" required="required" />

 </div>

 <div>
     <label for="form1_shipping_address_2">Address 2</label>
     <input id="form1_shipping_address_2" name="shipping_address_2" type="text" />
 </div>

 <div>
     <label for="form1_shipping_city">City</label>
     <input id="form1_shipping_city" name="shipping_city" type="text" />
 </div>
```

Now I need to replace every instance of `form1` with `idsplit[0]`. I have tried but it keeps failing. What is the best way of doing this?

For more clarification, the `form1` is being added to my input IDs by my CMS, so can't be removed. Also, if it were the second form on the page it would be `form2`, so I need to get the value as a variable from the DOM. I have done this, now I just need to get the variable into my jQuery wherever I have `form1` currently

Comment: Please provide relevant html samples. A demo would help also along with an explanation of purpose of this code

Comment: I have added the html and an explanation, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the javascript I have ended up with - passing the `idsplit` to a variable

```
$("#toshipping_checkbox").on("click",function(){

  var formid = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
  var idsplit = formid.split('_');
  var splitid =idsplit[0];
  var ship = $(this).is(":checked");

$('[id^="' + splitid + '_shipping_"]').each(function(){
    var tmpID = this.id.split(splitid + '_shipping_')[1];
    $(this).val(ship?$('#' + splitid + '_' + tmpID).val():'');
});
});
```